# How generate wsdl or/and client source from class with Spring @Endpoint by maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, wsdl

There is [jasws-maven-plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) which can be used to generate wsdl or/and client code from classes with @javax.jws.Webservice annotation. Is there plugin which can generate wsdl or/and client code from classes with spring **@Endpoint** (*org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint*) annotation?

**Important**

I **know** that there is org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition bean that scans classes with @Endpoint and generate wsdl. **But** this generation occurs in runtime! And I want to generate on compile time with maven plugin, **without** packaging web application and going to the some url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wsgen](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2/docs/wsgen.html) to generate the wsdl.

From the example in the documentation

wsgen -wsdl -d stock -cp myclasspath stock.StockService
This will generate the wsdl and schema files in the "stock" directory.

There is also a wsgen [Ant task](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2/docs/wsgenant.html).